Problem understanding conditional expectations as a projection
Let $(\Omega, \mathcal{A}, P)$ be a (complete) probability space and let $\mathcal{F}$ be a sub-$\sigma$-algebra of $\mathcal{A}$. Consider the mapping $1: \Omega \rightarrow \mathbb{R}, \, \omega \mapsto 1$. This mapping satisfies
\begin{align*}
1 = E(1 \, \vert \, \mathcal{F})
\end{align*}
since the $\sigma$-algebra generated by the constant mapping $1$ is the trivial $\sigma$-algebra $\lbrace \emptyset, \Omega \rbrace$. We know that the conditional expectation is the orthogonal projection. To be precise, $E(1 \, \vert \, \mathcal{F})$ is the orthogonal projection of $1$ onto $L^2((\Omega, \mathcal{F}), \mathbb{R})$ (= space of square integrable functions that are measurable w.r.t. $\mathcal{F}$). If we take an orthonormal basis $(e_i, i \in I)$ of $L^2((\Omega, \mathcal{F}), \mathbb{R})$ and extend it to an orthonormal basis of $L^2((\Omega, \mathcal{A}), \mathbb{R})$ which we call $(e_i, i \in \tilde{I})$ then clearly $I \subseteq \tilde{I}$. The function $1$ is an element of $L^2((\Omega, \mathcal{F}), \mathbb{R})$ and therefore it holds
\begin{align*}
\langle 1, e_i \rangle_{L^2} = 0
\end{align*}
for all $i \in \tilde{I} \setminus I$. If we now assume that $\mathcal{A} \neq \mathcal{F}$, then we may choose a set $B \in \mathcal{A} \setminus \mathcal{F}$ and let's assume that we can choose $B$ such that $P(B) > 0$. Then the indicator function $1_B$ to $B$ is an element of $L^2((\Omega, \mathcal{A}), \mathbb{R})$ but it is not an element of $L^2((\Omega, \mathcal{F}), \mathbb{R})$. Thus
\begin{align*}
\langle 1, 1_B \rangle_{L^2} = 0.
\end{align*}
But
\begin{align*}
\langle 1, 1_B \rangle_{L^2} = \int_\Omega 1_B \, d P = P(B) > 0.
\end{align*}
This is clearly a contradiction.
My question is: Where am I wrong? Surely, we can think of examples where we can choose such a set $B$ since $\mathcal{F}$ could be the trivial $\sigma$-algebra and $\mathcal{A}$ could be much broader. Then we can easily construct an example where we can find such a set $B$ with $P(B)>0$. I suppose that my understanding of the conditional expectation being an orthonormal projection is somewhat incorrect but I cannot spot my mistake.
Any help would be appreciated.

You're right that $1_B$ is not in $L^2((\Omega,\cal{F}),\mathbb{R})$ but this does not mean that $\langle 1,1_B\rangle_{L^2}=0$. In particular $1_B$ could have a non-zero 'component' from $(e_i,i\in I)$ even if it also has a component in $(e_i,i \in \bar{I}\setminus I)$.

To perhaps make it more clear: consider $e_i+e_j$ for some $i \in I$ and $j \in \bar{I}\setminus I$. This is not in $L^2((\Omega,\mathcal{F}),\mathbb{R})$ but it is still not orthogonal to $e_i$.

You are right, I falsely assumed that $1_B$ does not have a component in $L^2((\Omega, \mathcal{F}), \mathbb{R})$. Thank you for your help!

Is $1$ square integrable? Only if you integrate w.r.t. a finite measure, right?

Yes, since $P$ is a probability measure.
